# Pandas change Nan Columns values to True or False

Tags: python, pandas

I need to change a column to either True or False based on the NaN value.

Here is the df.

```
    missing

0      NaN
1      b
2      NaN
4      y
5      NaN
```

would become

```
    missing

0      False
1      True
2      False
4      True
5      False
```

yes I can do a loop but there was to be a simple way to do in a single line of code.

thank you.

Comment: `df['missing'].notna()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to overwrite the column values with binary applied on the same column, which can be achieved notna()

```
df['missing'] = df['missing'].notna()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
df['missing'].notna() # or notnull()
```